# JSHint Gulp to error window VS2015

Tags: gulp, jshint, visual-studio-2015

How can I get the output from JSHint to show up in my **Error List** in Visual Studio 2015 when using Gulp, rather than just output to the Task Runner?

I've tried [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-visual-studio) but that doesn't seem to do anything except format the Gulp output slightly differently.

This is my **gulpfile.js**:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src(["Scripts/**/*.js"])
        .pipe(jshint(".jshintrc"))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter("jshint-visual-studio"));
});
```

Actual output (in Task Runner Window):

[image: Actual output]

Preferred output (in Error List):

[image: Preferred output]

**Please Note:** I'm using Visual Studio 2015, so Web Essentials is no longer an option for JSHint as the functionality has been removed.

Comment: getting the console output to be formatted [in a way msbuild understands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx) should do the trick

Comment: @m0sa I think that's what the *jshint-visual-studio* does, but I think Gulp runs outside of MSBuild when using the in-built task runner. I guess I *could* set this up as a Pre-Build event using MSBuild and just run the `gulp` task via command line

Comment: you have [jshint vs extension](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/08/17/using-jshint-inside-visual-studio-the-basics/)... just use that. or you can use [web-essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript) which also does add errors to output

Comment: @entre I've added a note to this effect, but Web Essentials no longer supports JSHint (or anything really...it's redundant now) for Visual Studio 2015. I have tried that JSLint extension - that is **exactly** what I'm looking for, but in Gulp format. However, that extension doesn't seem to allow me to save my preferences in VS2015 so mustn't support it fully.

Comment: sorry i wasnt aware that web-essential does not support jshint for vs2015.. i am using vs2013, where it does work

Comment: according to @mkristensen: https://twitter.com/Eonasdan/status/605802922929094658 VS2015 is supposed to show errors (at some point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to get an official word on this from [Mads Kristensen](https://twitter.com/mkristensen) in this conversation on Twitter:

[image: Tweet]

So in VS2015RC (and RTM too), there is no way to get messages to go to the output window. The task runner only outputs to the error window if the Gulp task returns a failure - but honestly, I haven't managed to get this working either.

[He did also confirm](https://twitter.com/mkristensen/status/610170295035367425) that this kind of functionality will be coming post-RTM.

<sub>Thanks to Eonasdan for pointing this out!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Found a simple way to do this in VS2013, don't know if it works in 2015. Inside your jshint task in gulp just catch the error using jshints error event handler and log a message prefixed **"error:"** to the console. Visual Studio uses this convention to identify the errors that failed the build from the output.

```
.pipe(jshint({

// .... //

.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("error: JSHint failed.");
})
```

You'll see this in your ErrorList:

[image]

Comment: Does that display for every error, or just the first one?

Comment: Using `gulp sass` in VS2015, I can't get the error to show in the error list using this method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [gulp-jshint](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint) with following task definition:

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    gulp.src(["Scripts/**/*.js"])
      .pipe(jshint())
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
      .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
```

It will make gulp exit with code 1.
And for code 1 to fail build you need to go to Project settings, Build Events tab and add following code to Pre-build event command line:

```
gulp -b $(ProjectDir) --gulpfile $(ProjectDir)gulpfile.js lint
```

It will fail the build with following message:

```
Error   242 The command "ATTRIB -R gulp -b --gulpfile lint" exited with code 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have my jshint vs17 reporter (should work with prev. version too) :
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSluy.png)

1. Include the gulp run command to your msbuild process (.csproj) file

   ```
   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Exec Condition=" '$(IsTfsServerBuild)' == 'true' " Command="npm install" />
        <Exec Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Release' " Command="gulp --gulpfile &quot;$(ProjectDir)gulpfile.js&quot; --targetDir &quot;$([System.String]::Copy('$(TargetDir)').TrimEnd('\\'))&quot; --projectDir &quot;$([System.String]::Copy('$(ProjectDir)').TrimEnd('\\'))&quot; --configuration &quot;$(Configuration)&quot; --isTfs $(IsTfsServerBuild)" />
   ```
2. Create module file `gulp.jshint.vs.reporter.js`

```js
module.exports = jshintVSReporter;

function logVsError(file, line, col, message, code) {
    console.error(formatVsOutput("error", file, line, col, message, code));
}

function logVsWarning(file, line, col, message, code) {
    console.warn(formatVsOutput("warning", file, line, col, message, code));
}

/**
 * Formats the proper visual strudio output messange
 * @param {string} type - the messange type
 * @param {string} file - the file path
 * @param {number} line - the line no in file
 * @param {number} col - the cloumn no in line 
 * @param {string} message - the messange
 * @param {string} code - the error code
 * @returns {string} - vs-output-formated string
 */
function formatVsOutput(type, file, line, col, message, code, program) {
    var vsLine = (program ? program + ":" : "") + file;
    if (line) {
        vsLine += "(" + line;
        if (col) { vsLine += "," + col; }
        vsLine += ")";
    }
    vsLine += ": " + type;//(type||"warning");
    if (code) vsLine += " : " + code;
    if (message) { vsLine += ": " + message; }
    return vsLine;
}

/**
 * @typedef {Object} JSHintError
 * @property {string} id - usually '(error)'
 * @property {string} code - error/warning code ('WXXX' - warnings, 'EXXX' - errors, 'IXXX' - informations)
 * @property {string} reason - error/warning message
 * @property {string} evidence - a piece of code that generated this error
 * @property {number} line - the line in file number
 * @property {number} character - the erro cloumn in line numer
 * @property {string} scope - message scope, usually '(main)' unless the code was eval'ed
 *
 * @typedef {Object} JSHint
 * @property {string} file - file name
 * @property {JSHintError} error - the error description
 * 
 * The custom visual studio jhint reporter
 * @param {Array<JSHint>} errors - the jshint error list
 */
function jshintVSReporter(errors) {
    if (errors) {
        var file, i, error, isError, msg;
        for (i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            file = errors[i].file;
            error = errors[i].error;

            isError = error.code && error.code[0] === "E";
            msg = error.reason + " (jshint:" + error.code + ")";
            if (isError) {
                logVsError(file, error.line, error.character, msg, error.code, "JSHint");
            } else {
                logVsWarning(file, error.line, error.character, msg, error.code, "JSHint");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Import your local module `const vsJsHintReporter = require('./gulp.jshint.vs.reporter');`
5. Use in gulp task `.pipe(jshint(config.jshint)).pipe(jshint.reporter(vsJsHintReporter))`

**I'm planning to publish the reporter to npm.**

Answer (score 0):

[Source code](https://github.com/patricklafrance/jshint-visual-studio/blob/master/visual-studio.js) of [your package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jshint-visual-studio) (jshint-visual-studio) just add errors to `errors` array and log it to `console`. The code can't do anything to change `console` output, you must do it by yourself.

You can use [this plugin](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708).

Once the plugin is installed, open the *Task Runner Explorer* from the *View* –> *Other Windows* –> *Task Runner Explorer* menu.

This window will show you all the tasks in the gulp file and allow you to bind those tasks to certain Visual Studio events. This way, we don’t need to remember to run the gulp tasks from the command line. The IDE can handle it for us.

What I like to do is bind the *watch* task to the *Solution Load* event and bind the *scripts* task to the *Before Build* event.

[image]

With these bindings, we can make sure that all.min.js is correctly generated when we build the application and also regenerated anytime I make changes to the js files.

The Task Runner Explorer also shows the output of any running tasks. Here you can see the output from the watch task, which is always running in the background in this configuration.

[image]

[**From this article.**](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: I've already got the bindings set up and working fine. What I need is to get my output (specifically for JSHint) to show up in the Error List & optionally fail the build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it doesn't address the problem of displaying the results in the output window. Because of this I'm not going to award the bounty manually. You'll get half of the bounty in 24hours anyway because of the 2 upvotes

Comment: This answer is not relevant. The thing is that it got marked marked by such large bounty is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I have build fail (and error reporting) with gulp working (well enough for me, maybe sufficient for others.)

Here is what I used/did...

As per [this](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#scripts) page, I added/edited this in my **project**.json, which hooks into the prebuild event...

```
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": [ "gulp default" ]
  }
```

As per [this](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint#fail-reporter) page, I included the following for my jshint task...

```
// =============================
// jsHint - error detection
// =============================
gulp.task("jshint", function () {
    var jshGlobals = [
        '$',
        'jQuery',
        'window',
        'document',
        'Element',
        'Node',
        'console'
    ];

    gulp.src([paths.jsFiles, norefs])
        .pipe(jshint({
            predef: jshGlobals,
            undef: true,
            eqnull: true
        }))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
});
```

The latter two lines being the most significant. You will need to npm install `jshint-stylish` if you don't already have it.

Alternatively, for `jshint-stylish`, you can let VS handle it for you.  Add the line for `jshint-stylish` as indicated below to your **package**.json...

```
{
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "~3.1.2",
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "jshint": "~2.9.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "~6.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "~6.3.3"
  }
}
```

Which gives me this when there is an error (in addition to the failed build) which is sufficient for me to dig further if/as necessary...
[image: vs error list window after build]

As opposed to the more detailed error info I get when running the same task via command line or Task Runner...
[image: gulp default task output via cmd.exe]

I imagine this solution can be improved but figured I would share as I hadn't seen a whole lot about it elsewhere.

Cheers.